# Employer NOC not available while applying for Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen-visas, work

I have resigned from my current company and will be joining a new company. Within 2 weeks of joining the new company, I will be travelling to Europe. The issue is since I haven't joined the new company, they are unable to issue me a formal NOC.

What can be the alternatives proofs that I can show to the visa officer for the mandatory NOC?

Comment: The user hasn't provided solution in the post. I am looking for the alternatives proof that I can provide to the visa officer.

Comment: The post does says that you can make your case by providing your relieving letter from your old job and the offer letter from the new job.

Comment: I do not believe that a NOC is *mandatory*. Adding it is a *very good idea* to explain that/why you are going to leave the Schengen area again, but you will have to make your case by documenting the rest of your situation.